# scroll bar in scaling svg image

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I have the following D3 graph

```js
var width = 500, height = 300;
d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("id", "containerdiv");
// REMOVE OLD SVG
//d3.select("#wkfsvg").remove();
     
// ADD NEW SVG
var graphArea = d3.select("#containerdiv").append("svg")   
            .attr({ width: width, height: height, "pointer-events": "all" })
   .attr("id","wkfsvg");

var g = new dagreD3.graphlib.Graph().setGraph({});

graphArea.insert("g", "g");

var nodesJson = [
    {
        
        "nodes": "Initiate",
        "status": "startend",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Automatic"
    },
    {
       
        "nodes": "Find the Next Approver",
        "status": "completed",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Automatic"
    },
    {
        
        "nodes": "Check for Manager",
        "status": "completed",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Automatic"
    },
    {
        "nodes": "Set Status & ACL for IT Project Manager",
        "status": "completed",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Automatic"
    },
    {
       
        "nodes": "Set Status & ACL for IT Sign Off Approvers",
        "status": "completed",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
        
        "nodes": "IT Project Manager Approves",
        "status": "completed",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
        "id": "Finance Approver",
        "nodes": "Finance Approver",
        "status": "dormant",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
        
        "nodes": "Send Email for Completion",
        "status": "future",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
       
        "nodes": "Send to Requestor",
        "status": "future",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
        
        "nodes": "Send Email to Requestor",
        "status": "completed",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
        "id": "Set ACL on Form for Requestor",
        "nodes": "Set ACL on Form for Requestor",
        "status": "future",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
       
        "nodes": "Set Completion ACL on Form",
        "status": "future",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
         "id": "Set Completion ACL on PO",
        "nodes": "Set Completion ACL on PO",
        "status": "future",
         "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
       
        "nodes": "Set Completion ACL on Attachments",
        "status": "future",
         "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
       
        "nodes": "Set ACL on Attachment",
        "status": "completed",
         "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
        
        "nodes": "Update Comments of PM Rejection",
        "status": "future",
         "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
        
        "nodes": "Update Comments of FA Rejection",
        "status": "future",
         "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
        
        "nodes": "Update Comments of PM",
        "status": "completed",
         "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
        
        "nodes": "Update Comments of FA",
        "status": "future",
         "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
        
        "nodes": "Update Comments of Requestor",
        "status": "future",
         "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
       
        "nodes": "End",
        "status": "startend",
         "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    }
];      
 

// Automatically label each of the nodes
nodesJson.forEach(function(node) {
   
    if(node.status == "future") {
        if(node.execution_type == "Manual") {
            g.setNode(node.nodes, { labelType: "html", label: node.nodes+' <tspan dx="0" dy="-10">\uf007</tspan>', class: "future" });            
        } else {
            g.setNode(node.nodes, { label: node.nodes, class: "future" }); 
        }
    } else if(node.status == "completed") {
        if(node.execution_type == "Manual") {
            g.setNode(node.nodes, { labelType: "html", label: node.nodes+' <tspan dx="0" dy="-10">\uf007</tspan>', class: "completed" });
        } else {
            g.setNode(node.nodes, { label: node.nodes, class: "completed" }); 
        }
    } else if(node.status == "dormant") {
       if(node.execution_type == "Manual") {
            g.setNode(node.nodes, { labelType: "html", label: node.nodes, class: "dormant" });
        } else {
            g.setNode(node.nodes, { label: node.nodes, class: "dormant" }); 
        }
    } else if(node.status == "startend") {
        g.setNode(node.nodes, { label: node.nodes, class: "startend" }); 
    } else {
        g.setNode(node.nodes, { label: node.nodes });
    }   
});

var edgesJson = [
    {
 
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Find the Next Approver",
        "target": "Check for Manager"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Check for Manager",
        "target": "Set Status & ACL for IT Sign Off Approvers"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Check for Manager",
        "target": "Set Status & ACL for IT Project Manager"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Set Status & ACL for IT Project Manager",
        "target": "IT Project Manager Approves"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Set Status & ACL for IT Sign Off Approvers",
        "target": "Finance Approver"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Set ACL on Form for Requestor",
        "target": "Send to Requestor"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Set Completion ACL on Form",
        "target": "Set Completion ACL on PO"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "IT Project Manager Approves",
        "target": "Send Email to Requestor"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Set Completion ACL on PO",
        "target": "Set Completion ACL on Attachments"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Set Completion ACL on Attachments",
        "target": "Send Email for Completion"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Initiate",
        "target": "Set ACL on Attachment"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Set ACL on Attachment",
        "target": "Find the Next Approver"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Update Comments of PM Rejection",
        "target": "Set ACL on Form for Requestor"
    },
    {
        "type": "reject",
        "source": "IT Project Manager Approves",
        "target": "Update Comments of PM Rejection"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Update Comments of FA Rejection",
        "target": "Set ACL on Form for Requestor"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Send Email to Requestor",
        "target": "Update Comments of PM"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Update Comments of PM",
        "target": "Set Status & ACL for IT Sign Off Approvers"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Finance Approver",
        "target": "Update Comments of FA"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Update Comments of FA",
        "target": "Set Completion ACL on Form"
    },
    {
        "type": "reject",
        "source": "Finance Approver",
        "target": "Update Comments of FA Rejection"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Send to Requestor",
        "target": "Update Comments of Requestor"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Update Comments of Requestor",
        "target": "Check for Manager"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Send Email for Completion",
        "target": "End"
    }
]; 

edgesJson.forEach(function(edge) {
    if(edge.type == "approve") {
        g.setEdge(edge.source, edge.target, { label: "" }); 
    }
    // Make the edge of rejected paths red and dashed
   if(edge.type == "reject") {
        g.setEdge(edge.source, edge.target, {
            label: "", class: "rejectEdgePath"
            
        });
    }
});



 var inner = graphArea.select("g");

// Set the rankdir
//g.graph().rankdir = "LR";
g.graph().nodesep = 10;

// Set up zoom support
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function() {
      inner.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" +
                                  "scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    });
graphArea.call(zoom);

// Create the renderer
var render = new dagreD3.render();


// Run the renderer. This is what draws the final graph.
render(inner, g);

// Center the graph
var initialScale = 0.75;
zoom
  .translate([(graphArea.attr("width") - g.graph().width * initialScale) / 2, 20])
  .scale(initialScale)
  .event(graphArea);
//graphArea.attr('height', g.graph().height * initialScale + 40);

var selectedNode = inner.selectAll("g.node"); 
selectedNode.on('click', function (d) { 
    var nodeInfo = getNodeInfo(d);
    console.log('clicked '+nodeInfo.nodes+' (status: '+nodeInfo.status+')'); 
});

function getNodeInfo(name) {
    for (var i=0;i<nodesJson.length;i++) 
        if (nodesJson[i].nodes==name) return nodesJson[i]; 
}
```

```css
.node rect {
  stroke: #333;
  fill: #fff;
}

.edgePath path {
  stroke: #333;
  fill: #333;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.rejectEdgePath path {
  stroke: red;
  fill: red;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  stroke-dasharray: 5, 5;
}



g.dormant > rect { 
  fill: #CC66FF;
}

g.completed > rect { 
  fill: #66FF99;
}

g.future > rect { 
  fill: #99CCFF;
}

g.acquired > rect { 
  fill: #EBBFFF;
}

g.paused > rect { 
  fill: #FF0000;
}

g.startend > rect { 
  fill: #CC6666;
}

foreignobject {
   fill: black;
   font-family: FontAwesome;
   font-size: 15px;
   text-anchor: middle;
//   cursor: move;
}
#wkfsvg {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    overflow: auto;
}

#containerdiv {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cpettitt.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/dagre-d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

It works fine except for an issue related to scrolling.

Right now (without scrollbars), the complete diagram displays but part of it is hidden as it is outside the specified width and height. To see the hidden areas user need to drag the graph and bring it in the visible canvas (this would then hide some other areas as the graph is moved).

I need to provide a scrollbar so that instead of dragging the graph user can scroll up/down and left/right to view the complete graph.

I have tried providing a auto scroll in css for both div and svg elemment without any luck.

Can someone please help me in achieving this.

Comment: You need to add `overflow: scroll` To the styling of the element you want to have this behaviour.

Comment: It's added to svg. The graph is inside svg

Comment: your code says different... I said `scroll` not `auto` and if you [read the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) you will see that its not inherited.

Comment: Thanks again. scroll displays a scrollbar but not where it needs to be be. Graph which is outside the defined width and height is hidden http://jsfiddle.net/94pgg33y/36/